# Walking over walls - Game maker studio

Tags: game-maker, depth

I am having an issue with the walls in my game. I have set them as objects and used the script:

depth = -y;

inside their create event.

However, when I walk my character in front of them, the correct depth is only kept until the character kindof goes half in front of the wall.

Like this:

[image]

[image]

These are the collision shapes

[image]

[image]

And this shows how I inherit from one door parent and add the depth = -y; script to the create event of the wall child.

[image]

My character also has depth = -y; but on its step event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use `depth = -y;` in `Step End`, not `Step`.
2. Where is sprite's origin? It must be at bottom of the sprite (the lowest point of the sprite)(this applies to each object/sprite where used `depth = -y;`)

Comment: I added depth = -y; into the end step event, however its still having problems, I think the error must come from the origin of the character being almost in the middle and not in the bottom as you say, will check and come back if it works

Comment: worked well by re setting the origin of my characters sprites to the lowest pixel. Thanks!

Comment: @johan855 I meant that you had two different errors, not one of them. Because when you use `Step` instead `Step End` you may have a small lag between `y` and `depth` (for example, when you use `speed`, `hspeed`, `vspeed` and any other different from `x += value`).

Comment: Other than using the `depth = -y` snippet, you should also make sure sprite origins are properly set: since collision works upon collision masks, try to set the origin at the geometrical center of each mask, so that the player will never have a greater `y` value (thus a smaller `depth` value) than the wall object.